# Control.UniqueID different after cross-page postback

Tags: asp.net, unique-id

I have a simple ASP.NET page with a MasterPage.  Within the MasterPage, I have two login fields:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtUserName"/>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtPassword"/>
```

When the controls are rendered to the page, ASP.NET renders the following:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="ctl00_txtUserName" name="ctl00$txtUserName"/>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="ctl00_txtPassword" name="ctl00$txtPassword"/>
```

If I understand correctly, the `name` attribute corresponds to the `UniqueID` property of a control.  However, when I'm debugging `Page_Load` and attempt to view the `UniqueID` of these fields, they have different values (`ctl0$txtUserName` and `ctl0$txtPassword` respectively)!

Note that this does not seem to be an issue on all pages using this MasterPage. Most of them work correctly and use `ctl0$txtUserName` and `ctl0$txtPassword` in both rendering and `Page_Load`.

Any idea what might cause ASP.NET to render a different `UniqueID` for a control than it uses in `Page_Load`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what was causing the generated UniqueIDs in the MasterPage to be different in Page_Load than when rendered to the page.  However, I was able to get around the issue by storing the UniqueIDs of these fields in hidden fields.  I was then able to access the values directly in the Request.Form collection.

In other words, I did this:

In the MasterPage -

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtUserName"/>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="txtPassword"/>

<input type="hidden" id="txtUserNameUID" value="<%=txtUserName.UniqueID%>"/>
<input type="hidden" id="txtPasswordUID" value="<%=txtPassword.UniqueID%>"/>
```

During Page_Load of the child page -

```
string username = Request.Form[Request.Form["txtUserNameUID"]];
string password = Request.Form[Request.Form["txtPasswordUID"]];
```

Hope this helps anyone else struggling with UniqueID weirdness in ASP.NET!

Answer (score 0):

Weird quirk I just became aware of: any wrapping controls that are runat server must also have IDs. For instance, if you have a panel around the control, i.e. whatever "ctl00" is, it must be assigned an ID. If it is not set, it will be allocated one and this can change.